# Better way to check if subdomain exists without using database query or hosts file

Tags: php, apache, symfony, optimization, wildcard-subdomain

I'm using symfony2 and in my application for student accommodation, i'm creating dynamic subdomains for each university, i'm configuring the virtual host with the wildcard subdomain entry so any subdomain would be valid.

How do i check if a subdomain is registered and belongs to a university, and how do i differentiate it from a randomly typed ***non user registered*** subdomain efficiently?

if i go with a database query then every random access from curious users would result in a lot of db queries, and the use of hosts file would be too slow (not the best practice)

Please suggest an efficient way to do this using php or symfony or any other techniques you guys know of

(additional info) there will be a 'free trial' option so that would result in a lot of subdomains, as anyone and every one would start a free trial, a very good example of what i'm trying to achieve woudld be this [StudyStays](http://studystays.com.au/)

-thanks

Comment: @Epodax SO actually is a pretty good place to give suggestions.

Comment: How about caching database results and then you would only need to do a database call on a new subdomain request?

Comment: @Qoop how would i deal with deletion of subdomains? i will have to update the cache very frequently with every new entry and deletion

Comment: How often would subdomains need to be added and removed? Are they set to one subdomain per university or are they randomly created and removed? If they are created or deleted by a user then you can just add the cache update in that process, otherwise you will probably need to provide more information.

Comment: @Qoop we will be having a 'free trial' offering where anyone can try out the application, so there can be a lot of subdomains created and deleted, i guess i failed to mention that part, oops sorry!

Comment: i added a bit more info and links in my question guys

Comment: As there is a process where subdomains are added or retired/deleted you could just add the cache update in there, it would only be one extra call to set or unset (or set false) on flush.

Comment: @Qoop ok so i will try out your method, you could sum up your answer with some nice online tutorials that shows how to do it and post it as an answer to my question, if it works out i will accept your answer :) and also would using a data structure like binary tree or hash table to store all the subdomain names be better than caching? checking for uniqueness update and delete would be a breeze with these data structures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cache all each of the subdomain requests (using something like Doctrine cache as a wrapper for whatever caching system you use) so that each subsequent check would only need to check the cache rather than the database.

Also when adding/removing/updating your subdomain object you could update the cache value to keep it all up to date.

<kbd>app/config/config.yml</kbd>

*Set your provider for Doctrine Cache Bundle, for more info see [the docs](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCacheBundle) (you would need to add the Doctrine Cache Bundle to your vendors and AppKernel, obviously).*

```
doctrine_cache:
    providers:
        acme_subdomain:
            type: filesystem # apc, array, redis, etc
            namespace: acme_subdomain
```

<kbd>Acme\YourBundle\Registry\SubdomainRegistry</kbd>

*Create a registry that can check for the subdomain state and update the cache when required. This example stores the state as a string rather than a boolean as (as far as I know) a "not found" key will return a false rather than a null.*

```
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\Cache;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class SubdomainRegistry implements SubdomainRegistry
{
    const REGISTERED   = 'registered';
    const UNREGISTERED = 'unregistered';

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager
     */
    protected $manager;

    /**
     * @param Cache
     */
    protected $cache;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager, Cache $cache)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $subdomain
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isSubdomainRegistered($subdomain)
    {
        // If subdomain is not in cache update cache
        if (!$this->cache->has($subdomain)) {
            $this->updateRegistry($subdomain);
        }

        return self::REGISTERED === $this->cache->get($subdomain);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $subdomain
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function registerSubdomain($subdomain)
    {
        $this->cache->set($subdomain, self::REGISTERED);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $subdomain
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function unregisterSubdomain($subdomain)
    {
        $this->cache->set($subdomain, self::UNREGISTERED);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $subdomain
     * @return null
     */
    private function updateRegistry($subdomain)
    {
        $object = $this->manager->findOneBy(array('subdomain' => $subdomain);

        // $object->isActive() assume you are storing all subdomains after cancelling
        // and setting it to inactive. You could put your own real logic here
        if (null === $object || !$object->isActive()) {
            $this->unregisterSubdomain($subdomain);

            return null;
        }

        $this->registerSubdomain($subdomain);
    }
```

Then when you are registering or unregistering your subdomain you could add a call to the registry in the method.

For example...

```
$subdomain = new Subdomain();
// Subdomain as a property of subdomain seems weird to me
// but as I can't immediately think of anything better I'll go with it
$subdomain->setSubdomain('acme');
// .. subdomain details
$this->manager->persist($subdomain);
$this->manager->flush();
$this->registry->registerSubdomain($subdomain->getSubdomain());
```